# Acknowledgements chapter of master's thesis

Tags: thesis, masters, writing, acknowledgement

Hi due to the pandemic and my supervisor not using skype or zoom etc, I ended up writing my master's dissertation by myself. I had 2 meetings with him and we exchanged about 6-7 emails in total. I'd like to put him in the acknowledgements and thank him for his help and support. However, it really sounds fake because I just didn't reach out for much help and support. In any case, when I reached out, he was very helpful and I'm very grateful for this.

I'm just a bit worried how it sounds thanking for something that didn't happen, but I could be overthinking this. I've also thanked a couple of other lecturers because I really enjoyed their courses and they helped me learn a lot.

How do I acknowledge my supervisor in this situation?

Comment: May be related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/93865/68109

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @avid How do I approach the situation and acknowledge my supervisor?

Comment: You say that "he was helpful and I'm very grateful for this." So thank him for his help; you don't need to say that there was a huge amount of help.

Comment: Don't overthink it. Acknowledgements in a thesis don't matter for anything.

Comment: "This project was completed under the supervision of Prof X, and I gratefully acknowledge his support."

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound phony to thank him for support and for his help and encouragement. His help might have been technical, perhaps, or setting a direction, or even giving you a lot of latitude to work independently. Perhaps not all of those things, but likely some of them.

Some supervisors lean over you constantly. That might have been worse.

Don't overthink it. It is just a small politeness.